# Remote call to a PlayFramework object

Tags: java, sockets, rmi, playframework

I am looking for a way to send serialized objects (or simply strings) to a PlayFramework model or controller object through a remote JVM.

I am trying to create a web application based on pushed events, so for the moment, it is possible to get new events through a long polling ajax call, when some events are added to the model.

Now, I would like to add events into my model from a remote JVM, through RMI, a socket, or anything which could work. I have searched in the PlayFramework documentation but haven't found any API or piece of code on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebSockets, I wrote a blog post about it here:
http://geeks.aretotally.in/log4play-log4j-ui-mashed-up-with-play-framework-knockout-js-and-websockets

My example only pushes from server to client but you can use WebSockets for two-way communication through JSON:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/asynchronous#UsingWebSockets

You can also use Akka Remote Actors (http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.3/scala/remote-actors.html).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't pushing data into the server the easy part?

The natural way would be to invoke some controller action (read: HTTP POST) accepting a JsonData object (if data is structured) or plain parameters if data is unstructured.

Off the top of my head, in play speak it would look like this:

```
WSRequest request = new WSUrlFetch().newRequest("http://<url of your 'vm'>");
// request.setParameter("param", value);
// ...
request.post();
```

You do not need WebSockets for this.

Comment: Yea it's the easy part and you don't need WebSockets at all, just letting him know of some options he might not have stumbled on yet; WebSockets, if browser support is not an issue, would also avoid the long polling, its wasteful calls, and reuse the connection to the do the push.

Comment: Yes you are right, WebSockets totally make sense for an HTTP consumer. He could definitely switch from the long polling to WS if all infrastructure components are cooperative. But the external event producer (his remote VM) be it play or not can just make a traditional request to produce the events for the WS channel.

Comment: I don't want to (and was told not to) use some immature technology like WebSockets, as they are not supported by almost all web browsers yet and the standard is still to be by the W3C.
But the question of the frontend/backend communication using long polling is a solved problem, I am now focusing on the WS / backend communication.

To resume my architecture, I have a web backend pushing events to my frontend through long polling. The events pushed come from an independant webservice, and have to be placed into sort of a "buffer" in my backend before being pushed to the frontend.